# Let $\vec{F}$ be the vector field $\vec{F}$(x, y, z) = (z, x, y), Evaluate the surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{F}$ be the vector field $\vec{F}$(x, y, z) = (z, x, y). Let S be portion
of the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z = 1$ lying above the *xy*-plane, oriented upward. Evaluate the surface
integral

$\int_S
(Curl \vec{F}) · d\vec{S}
$

So I am trying to evaluate the surface integral by evaluating it directly, and also by applying Stokes' theorem to see how Stokes' theorem is effective. I am having trouble solving the surface integral with the boundary S (and how to set up the bounds). Can someone please walk me through this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, the curl is $$\nabla \times \vec F = \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial x}{\partial z},\frac{\partial z}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right) = (1,1,1)$$

Now to find $d\vec S$, we need to parametrize the surface. An obvious choice is $$\vec S(x,y) = (x, y, 1 - x^2 - y^2)$$
But this gives awkward limits of integration. Polar coordinates in the plane are nicer:
$$\vec S(r,\theta) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta, 1 - r^2)$$Then the limits of integration are $0 \le r \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. Now $$\frac {\partial \vec S}{\partial r} = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, -2r)\\\frac {\partial \vec S}{\partial \theta} = (-r\sin \theta, r\cos \theta, 0)$$
so $$\left(\frac{\partial \vec S}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec S}{\partial \theta}\right) = (2r^2\cos \theta, 2r^2\sin\theta, r)$$ which is outward pointing as desired (otherwise we could swap the order of the partials in the cross-product to get the opposite direction). So $$\iint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot d\vec S =  \iint(1,1,1)\cdot(2r^2\cos \theta, 2r^2\sin\theta, r)\,d\theta dr\\= \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}2r^2(\cos \theta + \sin\theta) + r\, d\theta dr = \pi$$

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you. How would I solve it using Stokes’ theorem though?

Comment: In much the same way I did the above. Denoting the boundary by $C = \partial S$, the other side of Stokes theorem is $$\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec C = \int_I \vec F(\vec C(t)) \cdot \vec C(t)\, dt$$ for some parametrization $\vec C : I \to C$. Since $C$ is just the unit circle in the $xy$ plane, there is an obvious parametrization. The one thing that you need to be careful about is that the orientation of $C$ be compatible with the orientation of $S$ - otherwise you'll get the opposite of the correct answer. Use the RH rule to relate them.

Comment: Okay i'm kinda confused, so what you did originally isn't Stokes' theorem, correct? Can you show the computation of Stokes' if possible? Thanks

Comment: Stoke's Theorem says $$\iint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot d\vec S =\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec C$$ As per the question you asked in your post, my answer shows how to calclulate the side with the surface integral. In my previous comment, I outlined how to handle the boundary integral on the other side. What I am confused about is what in the world you are expecting???

Comment: Oh I understand now. Can you please show the computation for Stokes' theorem, though? Like the process calculated out.

Comment: No. I've already done enough. I've done one side, and given you a straight-forward path on the other, simpler, side. It's time for you to put in some effort yourself. My simply telling you obviously hasn't been effective so far, and I see no hope for that to change. You need to do some work.